# Unpacking or split .BIN firmware for router device

Tags: firmware, unpacking

Sorry for my question, i'm newbie! so i'm trying to split or unpack this file mobile_update.bin, it is an firmware for routeur device.

(Based on qualcomm 9x07 and secureboot device also), i'm trying with 7zip or binwalk but error. Someone says me that it easy to unpack but  really, i have a headache to try with my little knwoledge.

[image: binwalk]

Could you help me or give idea to unpack this please?
Thank you very much !

[link > mobile_update](https://www.mediafire.com/file/4kwemp621hq005v/mobile_update.zip/file)

(sorry for my English is so bad)